# Comparison of UIActionSheet title fails

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, ios6, uiactionsheet

I am having an issue only with iOS 6.
This piece of code works for all other versions.
I don't get any warnings.

The code just does not go in the `if` conditions.
It's not able to compare `present.title` with the string `Select Goal` even though NSLog displays the value for buttonTitle correctly as "Select Goal".

```m
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)presentSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    NSString *buttonTitle=[presentSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    NSLog(@"button title  is %@", buttonTitle);

    actionSheet.delegate =self;
    if (presentSheet.title == @"Select Goal") {
        self.goalsTextField.text =buttonTitle;
        [self.goalsTextField resignFirstResponder];

    }

    if (presentSheet.title ==@"Select Level") {
        self.levelTextField.text =buttonTitle;
        [self.levelTextField resignFirstResponder];

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do string comparisons with `==`, use `isEqualToString:`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the comparison fails, but may I interest you in [`UIActionSheet+Blocks`](https://github.com/jivadevoe/UIAlertView-Blocks)?  I've always considered `UIAlertView` and `UIActionSheet` to have a pretty lousy callback API just because it is very fragile to code changes and sort of messy for run time argument checks for buttons.

`UIAlertView+Blocks` and `UIActionSheet+Blocks` will give you a block based API where you can more easily dynamically determine what options to present to a user, but even more important, execute a block on what should happen when a user makes a selection.  This API make is infinitely less fragile and error prone for you the developer.  It also makes it so that you don't have to do any conditional coding when you have multiple alerts and action sheets in a view controller.  All around, it is pure win.  I am greatly puzzled why Apple have not created a blocks based API in UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare string values using `==`, you are trying to compare NSString **objects** and by writing a statement like `presentSheet.title == @"Select Goal"`**you are comparing object pointers** *(i.e. memory locations, which will not always be the same. Probably almost never in fact.)*, and **not the string values** you think you're comparing.

To compare string values there are NSString methods, the one you'll need is:

```
if([presentSheet.title isEqualToString:@"Select Goal"])
```

That should do it.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, yet up until iOS6 everywhere you go on the web, this is common behavior for handling alerts events and it worked just fine... so both options were valid. any idea what has changed?

Comment: I don't see how that could ever work reliably... Can you show me some examples? I've never seen it before.